# regex from menu overwrites my jquery toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im using a regex to show the currently activated menu button, but it seems to overwrite one of my other scripts, which i don't understand why, since everything else works as it should.

the menu code is this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
$(function () {
  var url   = window.location.pathname,
  urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");

  $('#myTopnav a').each(function () {
    if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).parent().previoussibling().find('a').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow         : hidden;
  background-color : black;
  width            : 100%;
  }
.topnav a {
  color            : white;
  text-align       : center;
  padding          : 1vw 1.5vw;
  float            : left;
  display          : block;
  font-weight      : bold;
  font-size        : 1.2em;
  background-color : #000a1a;
  width            : 16.18%;
  }
.topnav a:hover {
  background-image : linear-gradient(#FFFFFF,#80b3ff, #1a75ff,#003d99, #000000);
  color            : white;
  text-decoration  : underline;
  font-weight      : bold;
  }
.topnav a.active {
  background-image : linear-gradient(#FFFFFF,#80b3ff, #1a75ff,#003d99, #000000);
  color            : white;
  text-decoration  : underline;
  font-weight      : bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"  />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a class="links" href="#">Forside</a>
    <a class="links" href="#">Åbningstider</a>
    <a class="links" href="#">Kontakt os</a>
    <a class="links" href="#">Fiskeliste</a>
    <a class="links" href="#">Billeder</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
 </div>
```

The code it seems to overwrite is this however:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("td").closest("tr").closest("tbody").next("tbody").slideToggle(1000);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("tbody tr#searchresult").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Any chance someone can give an explanation on my problem ?

Comment: this is the first time that I see this type of use: compute a regular expression by another regular expression, which then tests the result of a regular expression! you are not afraid of anything!

Comment: Welcome to Stack OVerflow. None of the Top Nav elements have a `/` is them. Since they are all `#`, I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes.. I removed the links, cause it thought it was more convenient if the snippet didn’t try to load the pages